# Show screen time in menu bar

Tags: menu-bar, screen-time

I would like to show the official "screen time" macOS usage time in the menu bar, so that I immediately see how long the Mac has been used today.

Is there an application for that, or does OSX has some in-built functionality for that?

(related to [Screen Time Menu Bar Application](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/rvckwy/screen_time_menu_bar_application/), but using the official screen time calculation)